# Issues with 2.82a Mantaflow Fluid - Am I the only one?

Tags: animation

I've been working with the new Mantaflow Fluid Simulator and have had some successes and a lot of FAILURE.  Thanks to the awesome tutorials by Blender Mania, CG Geek, Jonathan Kron, Blender Made Easy, I have been able to create some very nice Fluid animations.  (I also READ the on-line manual at Blender.org).  Here are the issues I am having and would like to know if others are having them also (operator error or bugs?)

1. After successfully creating a very simple simulation (1 cube as the flow, 1 cube as the Domain) I decide I want to change the size of the domain.  I scale it up, Free the Data - re-Bake - No particles.  No matter what I do now, I cannot make the particles reappear.
2. If I DELETE the Domain Cube, recreate it, RE-Bake, the particles reappear but remain INSIDE the Flow Cube (geometry)
3. Delete the Flow Cube, re-create it, rebake, all works again.
4. Scale up the Domain - Works (second domain cube)

Next Issue...

1. I create a beautiful Fluid Animation with water materials, Spray, Foam, Bubbles, particles, Environment, effectors, etc. Save the Blend file.  When I reopen, nothing works.  Animation wont play, Rebake does not work, and the Domain is filled with a haze.[image]